# How to extract a row without index from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wanting to create a multiple column plot, with the values of a variable each month for four years, grouped by year. So, each year is one point on the X-axis, with 12 columns.

To do this I've created the dataframe, `df_all`, which contains the values:

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame({"month": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                      "2016": bars_16["value"],
                      "2017": bars_17["value"],
                      "2018": bars_18["value"],
                      "2019": bars_19["value"]})
df_all = df_all.set_index("month")
df_all.head()
```

It looks like:

```
    2016    2017    2018    2019
month               
Jan 0   1016340 1815983 3163752
Feb 0   871166  1839012 2967114
Mar 0   910442  1943507 2827649
Apr 0   926362  1870525 2681053
May 97162   1061573 1753449 2834637
```

I want to slice every month's value out into a series of four numbers, like getting a `jan` variable equal to `[0, 1016340, 1815983, 3163752]`

I tried the following:

```
jan = df_all.loc["Jan", :]
feb = df_all.loc["Feb", :]
mar = df_all.loc["Mar", :]
apr = df_all.loc["Apr", :]
may = df_all.loc["May", :]
jun = df_all.loc["Jun", :]
jul = df_all.loc["Jul", :]
aug = df_all.loc["Aug", :]
sep = df_all.loc["Sep", :]
octo = df_all.loc["Oct", :]
nov = df_all.loc["Nov", :]
dec = df_all.loc["Dec", :]
```

But what I got is this (using `jan` as an example):

```
2016          0
2017    1016340
2018    1815983
2019    3163752
```

It seems that I'm getting the top index of the years. How should I just get the values in the rows themselves? Or is there a way to remove the `[2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]` from `jan` through `dec`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
rows = {month: row.to_list() for month, row in df.iterrows()}

jan = rows["jan"]  # [0, 1016340, 1815983, 3163752]
feb = rows["feb"]  # [0, 871166, 1839012, 2967114]
mar = rows["mar"]  # [0, 910442, 1943507, 2827649]
...
```